# How can I direct the output of awk to multiple individual files in a specified directory

Tags: shell, awk

I'm having trouble directing the output of awk into individual files in a specified directory.  I can successfully do this in the working directory as well as chaining a mv command to the end, but I would like to be able to use only `awk` to save the files to the specified directory.

For reference, here is a simplified `messages.txt` that I want to split into individual message files:

```
messageHeader:
  mh_field1: mh_val1
  mh_field2: mh_val2
messageData:
  md_field1: md_val1
  md_field2: md_val2

messageHeader:
  mh_field1: mh_val1
  mh_field2: mh_val2
messageData:
  md_field1: md_val1
  md_field2: md_val2

messageHeader:
  mh_field1: mh_val1
  mh_field2: mh_val2
messageData:
  md_field1: md_val1
  md_field2: md_val2
```

I was able to successfully split the messages file into individual messages and output each to a separate file in the working directory using:

```
awk -v RS= '{print > ("message" NR ".txt")}'
```

Which creates `message1.txt`, `message2.txt`, and `message3.txt` in the working directory.  I can also chain a `mv` command to the end of this basic command like so to move the output into a specified directory:

```
out = "$(pwd)/messages"
mkdir -p $out
awk -v RS= '{print > ("message" NR ".txt")}' && mv message*.txt $out
```

Which creates `message1.txt`, `message2.txt`, and `message3.txt` in `./messages`.  However, I haven't been able to figure how to save the separate message files to a specified directory only using `awk`.

For example, I attempted to split the message file and output individual messages to a specified output directory as follows:

```
out="$(pwd)/messages"
mkdir -p $out
awk -v RS= '{print > ($out "message" NR ".txt")}' messages.txt
```

Which results in the following error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: can't redirect to 'messageHeader:
  mh_field1: mh_val1 
  mh_field2: mh_val2
messageData:
  md_field1: md_val1
  md_field2: md_val2message1.txt' (file name too long)
```

I found the following related question "[Split files using awk and generate the results in another directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241725/split-files-using-awk-and-generate-the-results-in-another-directory)" but still wasn't able to get the correct syntax.

```
out="$(pwd)/messages"
mkdir -p $out
awk -v RS= path=$out '{f=path "message" NR ".txt"; print > f}' messages.txt 

awk: fatal: cannot open file `{f=path "message" NR ".txt"; print > f}' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: You're just missing a `-v` I think ... `awk -v RS= -v path="$out"`

Comment: Did you really type ```out = "$(pwd)/messages"```? Did it give you an error message?

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, that was it, I was missing the `-v` before `path=$out`.

Comment: @Scott Sorry, that was error in writing the question.  I didn't initially have the `out` defined in that code block and made and error when I was trying to add that in for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @steeldriver's comment, there was a missing `-v`, making the correct syntax:

```
out="$(pwd)/messages"
mkdir -p $out
awk -v RS= -v path="$out" '{f=path "message" NR ".txt"; print > f}' messages.txt
```